# Database Permissions Required in SQL Server for Tridion Users

Tags: 2011, 2009, database

Do I need to give sys_admin privilege to any users in the database?

It does not seems to be required, please suggest.

Also, apart from the MTSUser (COM user), is there any other user for which I need to give access to the database sever (Deployer/Web)?

List of users need access in database and roles, this is what I am looking for, I am also going through documents available, any suggestion is mostly welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only one user needs database access, and that's the "TCMDBUSER" account. The MTSUser account does not need any database permissions.

In Tridion CM in 2011, you'll have just one user account (default: TCMDBUSER) and in CD you *may* have multiple users depending on number of databases. None of these users is a "Tridion user", they're purely DB users.

You will need one account with some special privileges (SA in SQL Server, "Tridion_Sys" in Oracle) to *create* the database, but this user account is not needed anymore once the database is created.

In SQL Server, the TCMDBUSER account only needs Data_Reader and Data_Writer roles, IIRC.

Comment: Just one query, TCMDBUSER will require SA privilege in sql sever. Can you please let me know why and what is actually role/responsibility of this user?

Comment: It does not require SA. It requires SA login to be created (and to create the databases), but the TCMDBUSER account is not an SA.

Answer (score 4):

In Addition to Nuno's Answar, you may need 'tcmlogdbuser' a Database account for the Logging database.

for more details, here is the [Summary of Tridion user accounts](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US#docid=concept_B64837DA693F4BA083057C85A7BD2D28&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=CM_UserAccounts.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_B64837DA693F4BA083057C85A7BD2D28&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US&action=search&query=MTSUSER&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1392903307425&currentQuery=MTSUSER&currentScope=)(Login Required) and [Content Manager databases security settings](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US#docid=concept_2AC91236EA9649529BF13A1640A2B6B1&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=CM_SecuritySettings_db.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_2AC91236EA9649529BF13A1640A2B6B1&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011&lang=en-US&action=search&query=MTSUSER&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1392903307425&currentQuery=MTSUSER&currentScope=) (Login Required).

Comment: Just FYI, but starting Tridion 2013 there will be no more Tridion_cm_log DB. Thus, tcmlogdbuser will no longer exist as well

Comment: Yes, here it is 2011, I am aware of this and many thanks to all for the information.